# Dependency failed for Local File System - booting Debian

Tags: debian, mount, boot, dependencies

I have been looking quite thoroughly on the internet for an answer to this strange issue that suddenly appeared :

My Debian distribution (4.9.0-6-686) boots with the failure message :

- [DEPEND] Dependency failed for Local File Systems
- [DEPEND] Dependency failed for Load/Save Random Seed
- [DEPEND] Dependency failed for Network Time Synchronization
- [ TIME ] Timed out waiting for device dev-sdb8.device
- [DEPEND] Dependency failed for /tmp

The function of the dev-sdb8.device /tmp is only for temporary files as the name implies.

But, this happens with all my mount points, who is connected to a SAS BIOS and SAS hard-drives. /boot /var /tmp swap - etc.

After trying to change fstab, to correct eventual errors and replacing UUID's with device names ... etc. This does not change anything.

I have seen some people have issues with wrong fstab entries, and some have changed a parameter called CONFIG_HANDLE. My fstab looks good, and the parameter seem to be set to yes, when I mount the /boot drive.

Some say that this is a systemd/udev thing or a mdadm problem, causing the mounting to happen before the device is available. I don't really understand this since the devices seem to load perfectly during boot, and my Raid is not running, as it is only in mode 0.

Mounting the devices after booting with init=/bin/bash seems to work, where it seem to "recover" the device before mounting it. After this all the [DEPEND] failures disappeared and the [ TIME ] messages remains.... all the devices get the [ TIME ] Timed out waiting for device HDD_NAME, and all the dev-sdbX.device on this harddrive.

I tried to boot in recovery mode, and got a systemd[] : Time has been changed message who spammed the boot, and did not go away. I had to boot in bash due to this. But I got a feeling that this timing issue might influence the boot, if timing is important?

Suddenly, after manually booting in bash, and mounting all drives manually, I managed to boot in recovery mode, without the "Time has been changed" message. 
I think I changed the bios clock, due to the time message.
After this, I booted normally as nothing had happened. I assume that this might happen again, and this is not wanted due to the systems critical nature.

My question is simple:

- How do I debug this problem?

This seem to be a time consuming issue, unless someone know something about this problem.

Comment: Please explain (by expanding your question) the role of `/dev/sdb8` in your system.

Comment: Kacie, was that you trying to edit the question? If you log into your original account, your edits will be visible immediately. If you forgot your credentials, please see the FAQ on how to recover your account. Thank you.

Comment: Yes ... I did not know that you could edit posts anonymously. But it seem to be visible now, after logging in.

Comment: Latest comment to my own question is that when booting, I still get time issues, as the time is locked in July 8'th, and the mounting is complaining about something happening in the future. I disabled the ntp through "timedatectl set- ntp false" and setting the new time. I might suspect that the new Firewall prevent the time to synchronize.